# jni and using c++ new'ed objects in java

Tags: java-native-interface

I have a c++ layer that talks to a db, this c++ layer does a new SomeObject() and returns it to java.

When is it safe for me to say delete SomeObject via my clean jni call.  Can I delete as soon as java has the returned object or do I need to copy the object and then delete?

Comment: How do you return a C++ object directly to Java? Don't you have to use the JNI environment to instantiate the appropriate Java object?

Comment: Yeah, that is kinda what I thought, I am in a new place and I am looking at this not code and I am not sure all the pieces are in place.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Daff wrote, you can't “return a C++ object to Java,” but what you can do is return the address of the object, as a long:

```
jlong obj_ptr = reinterpret_cast<jlong>( &obj );
```

You should make sure somewhere in a root header that the size of jlong is enough to hold pointers (it generally should be, as a Java long is 64-bit wide). I use Boost's static assert to check this:

```
#include <boost/static_assert.hpp>
BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof(jlong)>=sizeof(void *));
```

The C++ object should live as long as it (or its data) is needed, be it in Java or C++ — anyway, it can't be deleted by Java directly. When you determine that you can safely delete it, you can make another JNI call from java, passing the long value, cast it to the appropriate pointer with a `reinterpret_cast<SomeObject *>( the_jlong_value )`, and delete it. Of course, you have to delete it manually, the JVM is totally unaware of its existence, and all caveats of manual memory management apply...

Comment: don't need anymore I left the terrible company where I needed to do this.

Comment: In example above, obj must be declared in a global scope. Otherwise it may return stack address, which is invalid as soon the containing function returns..

Comment: You don't mean "declared in a global scope." You mean "allocated on the heap and not on the stack."